# saving contents to a html file

Tags: c#-4.0

html contents are coming from the server in a xml file. i have seprated the html contents from xml now  i want to save these contents to a html file. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Research the "System.IO" namespace. It contains all the classes and types you'll need to interact with the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Would take only one line in C#: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText( System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments + "myhtmlfile.html", "<html>...</html>", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 );`